# How to browse windows libraries in Powershel?

Tags: powershell

I feel like an idiot. For the past few days I have been working on a module that allows me to create windows libraries, add items or remove items to it. etc etc, thanks to a discovery I made that libraries are just `.xml` files

This whole time I was viewing the libraries in Explorer, Search Everything, Directory Opus. Which all have support for working with libraries.

Well how does does one browse a library in Powershell?
Lets say I have library called **Config Files**, how can I do something like:

```
Get-Child Items -Path "Libraries\Config Files"
```

Which should Output:

```
C:\Users\someuser\Documents\output.json
C:\Users\someuser\ParsLib\Real Time Config.sublime-project
C:\Users\someuser\Lime\Settings.json
C:\Users\someuser\Documents\Config Notes.md
<...>
```

Comment: When you crosspost the same question at the same time to different forums you should at least post links to the other forums along with your question to avoid people willing to help you making their work twice or more.Thanks [Your post on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/zya8av/how_to_browse_windows_libraries_in_powershel/)

Comment: get-childitem ?

Comment: I commend to your attention https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/weekend-scripter-working-with-windows-libraries/

Comment: @Olaf, I hear it loud and clear boss. I am working on the module to do that but I will manuall it for now.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin sweet! it looks promising. I will fall back to this, if I cant find a way, I was hoping there would be a built in way but alas. Thanks!

Comment: @js2010 I tried variations of this at first. I kept getting nothing, Maybe I am putting in the virutal path wrong. I will mess around some more. Thanks!